# Why is script assigned to overgridimage in Sheets Add-On running forever for G Suite organization user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-workspace, google-apps-script-addon

We have a G Suite account that seems to be correctly set up. Google Sheets Editor Add-On is installed domain-wide. Users are assigned to organizational units that can access and use the Add-On.  Opening Sheets loads the Menu as written in the published script.

But some of the sheets have overGridImages with assigned scripts that work like macro buttons.  Sheets can locate the assigned script but when the button is clicked, they see the [green "Running script" alert](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N52j0.png)
[image]
 indefinitely, and nothing happens.  If they call the same function through the Menu, it runs correctly.

I've tried every variation of the webapp settings in the json manifest and published every combination.  The script currently has

```
  "webapp": {
    "access": "ANYONE",
    "executeAs": "USER_ACCESSING"
```

I've also tried including this in the code.gs file:

```
/**
 * @NotOnlyCurrentDoc
 */
```

I can't figure out which settings will allow the function to run from the overGridImage. This script file is long and I don't think it will help to post the function script here, since the script already works correctly when launched from the Menu.

The kicker is that I am the code author, the owner of the Sheets and Drive folders, and the Super Admin for the G Suite account.  The overGridImage buttons launch the functions for me every time in every spreadsheet. How do I make that happen for all my other users?

**EDITED 3/16 8:30am

I realize now that deploying as webapp was the wrong way to go here. My script doesn't even have doGet() or doPost().  (Sorry, inexperienced coder trying lots of different things).  Let me back up and provide a sample.

Since my issue is with users in my domain organization, I've created a dummy account example@southwestscenic.com.  Please log in to Google with this account. Password is Dummy@ccount!

I've created a Google Sheet named "Hello World" and shared it with this dummy account. In the Sheet, an image "Run" serves as the function launch button. I've assigned the script "aa" to the image.

In my script file, I've written:

```
function aa(){
Browser.msgBox("Hello World!");
}
```

I've also added the same function as a Menu item:

```
      .addItem("Hello World", "aa")
```

You will notice that the function runs when selected from the Menu, but not when launched from the image. My script file contains other functions that I need users to be able to access from any Sheet, which is why I created the Add-On in the first place.  Unfortunately, forcing them to launch functions from the Menu is just not practical for all of the functions.

Comment: You said it was a webapp.  How does it get launched? Also could you please provide [mcve]

Comment: As said by @Cooper you don't need to post the whole script in here just the part that is giving you problems. So in this case the `doGet` or `doPost` functions that you have created for your WebApp. How is that they are seeing the `Running Script` if you are calling a webapp? I don't understand that.